# implicit declaration of function ZAssert is invalid in C99

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have this like of code:

```
ZAssert(modelURL, @"Failed to find model URL");
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
implicit declaration of function ZAssert is invalid in C99
```

Any of you knows why or how can I fixed?

Comment: What is ZAssert and where do you define it?

Comment: that is my problem. I don't know

Comment: so why are you using it? Might want to read about NSAssert

Comment: I'm inheriting this code from some one else.

Comment: An assert is a check to make sure that some assumption is valid. That check ensures that modelURL exists, if not it throws an exception. You can replace it with a different assert

Comment: this is my code:  NSURL *modelURL=[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DataModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
    ZAssert(modelURL, @"Failed to find model URL");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ZAssert` is likely to be an assertion macro that was copied from somewhere or in a file now not part of your code base. It loos to perform a standard function so you can simply replace it with:

```
NSAssert(modelURL, @"Failed to find model URL");
```

Which will check that modelURL is set and thrown an exception if not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the ZAsset macro I found out of the Core Data book of Marcus S. Zarra

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define MCRelease(x) [x release]
#define DLog(...) NSLog(@"%s(%p) %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, self, [NSString    stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__])
#define ALog(...) {NSLog(@"%s(%p) %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, self, [NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__]);[[NSAssertionHandler currentHandler] handleFailureInFunction:[NSString stringWithCString:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] file:[NSString stringWithCString:__FILE__ encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] lineNumber:__LINE__ description:__VA_ARGS__];}
#else
#define MCRelease(x) [x release], x = nil
#define DLog(...) do { } while (0)
#ifndef NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS
#define NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS
#endif
#define ALog(...) NSLog(@"%s(%p) %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, self, [NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__])
#endif

#define ZAssert(condition, ...) do { if (!(condition)) { ALog(__VA_ARGS__); }} while(0)
```

Comment: Interesting. It would be nice to have some explanation on what are the merits of using this instead on NSAssert.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/02/my-current-prefix-pch-file/